# Estimating curvature of oscillatory curve based on global constraints

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics, curvature

I have a heuristic question about using global constraints of a problem to make estimates of local features of a curve, such as its curvature.

Consider a suitably well behaved function on $\mathbb{R}$, denoted $f(x,t)$, where $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$ denotes time. Now, $f(x,t)$ is oscillatory and decays in a suitable fashion as $x\to \pm \infty$. Due to symmetries of the problem, I know that the number of waves (in this context I believe it's the same as saying number of zero crossings) of the function remains constant with respect to time.

Quantitatively this is the statement that

$\frac{d N(t)}{dt} \equiv \frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x,t)|^2 \ dx =0$.

Next, by exploiting other conservation laws, I know that the variance of the signal goes to zero, i.e.

$V(t)  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-\bar{x})^2 |f(x,t)|^2 \ dx \to 0 $

in $t$ finite, where

$\bar{x} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x |f(x,t)|^2\ dx$.

Now, I want to make a quantitative statement about the magnitude of the curvature, which for a graph is defined as

$\kappa = \frac{|f''|}{(1+f'^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$,

where primes $'$ denote differentiation with respect to x.

My question is, how can I use the information I have about $V(t)$, as well as $N(t)$, to make a statement about the local curvature of $f(x,t)$? Naively, it seems easy to see that as $V(t)$ goes to 0, the curvature must get large, as the number of oscillations stays fixed, but exactly how to quantify this is beyond me.

Any insights are appreciated.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you think $\int |f|^2$ is related to the number of zero crossing, but perhaps this does not matter. There is no way to bound the curvature from above based on the information given: integrals involving $f$ do not control the derivatives of $f$. To give a lower bound for the curvature, you can argue as follows. Suppose $\kappa\le 1/R$ around $\bar x$. Pick a point $x_0$ near $\bar x$ where $|f|$ is large and attains its maximum (such a point exists because $|f|$ is tightly localized). Let's assume $f(x_0)>0$ to simplify writing. By the curvature assumption, the graph of  $f $ lies above a circle of radius $R$ that is tangent to the graph from below. In a formula, $$f(x)\ge f(x_0)+\sqrt{R^2-(x-x_0)^2}-R,\quad |x-x_0|\le R$$
Actually, the simpler bound $f(x)\ge f(x_0) -R$ should be enough. The conclusion will be that the variance of $f$ is at least of order $R^2$. Hence, the curvature is bounded from below by  $C/\sqrt{V}$.

None of this uses the wavy information about $f$. It's possible that knowing some PDE that $f$ satisfies, one could say much more about the curvature.

It's also possible that looking at curvature isn't what you want, and $|f''|$ should be substituted for $\kappa$.